# c# avl tree deleting specific numbers gives System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, avl-tree

I have used this code [from this website](https://simpledevcode.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/avl-tree-in-c/comment-page-1/#comment-315) to practice with avl tree, but when i change the first bit from

```
        tree.Add(2);
        tree.Add(1);
        tree.Add(0);
        tree.Add(-1);
        tree.Add(-2);
        tree.Add(3);
        tree.Add(5);
        tree.Add(4);

        tree.DisplayTree();
```

to

```
        tree.Add(5);
        tree.Add(3);
        tree.Add(7);
        tree.Add(8);
        tree.Delete(3);
        tree.DisplayTree();
```

I get a `System.NullReferenceException` error . if I delete 7 instead of 3 I won't get that error . Does anyone know why this happens ?

Comment: Please do enough debugging so that you can get to a point where your question asks more than just "why does `NullReferenceException` get thrown?" If, once you do, you still are having trouble, post a new question with a good [mcve], along with a precise description of what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: Change your  balance_factor method into this.
private int balance_factor(Node current)
    {
        if (current.left != null)
        {
            int l = getHeight(current.left);
            int r = getHeight(current.right);
            int b_factor = l - r;
            return b_factor;
        }
        return 0;
    }

Comment: Hi. I am the author of the post and I have already fixed this issue as of now. The bug was in both the private and public Delete methods. The main issue was in the checking for a RR case and then reassigning the proper root node after the correction. Once again thanks for detecting this error and for your feedback. I have tested further cases & scenarios to double check my updated solution as well.